# Why is part of my wall shiny after cleaning it?

Tags: walls, paint, cleaning

I have recently moved to a new house and there have been a lot of deliveries for appliances and furniture. In the process there were some stains on the wall, nothing major as the paint was intact. I tried to use a soft microfiber cloth damped with hot water to gently rub off the stains.

However, after cleaning, that part strikes out a lot shinny than the rest of the wall when looked at an angle due to reflection of light. As this is the main part of the wall visible from the entrance, it really looks bad.
[image]

Has anyone faced the same issue and fixed it somehow? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You've essentially polished out the matte/eggshell sheen of the paint. This is partly why those sheens aren't considered washable. I don't have a good solution other than a fresh coat. Is the paint available?

Comment: Oh man. That sounds bad. I guess need to check with the builder for the paint. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should get some extra paint keep on hand anyway while the brand is current and the color mix is valid. Since the home is new, you can simply roll over the washed area and blend out in a radial pattern, working to a dry roll. Your shiny spot should all but disappear.

If the color isn't an identical match, paint the entire wall to the corners without bothering to mask or edge to the base trim or ceiling. It'll be quick and the edging shouldn't show much at all.

If you're new to painting, do a little reading and dive in. It's a great skill for any homeowner to possess.

Comment: Most of us have probably learned this the hard way.+

Comment: I just checked that I have the paint with me. Do you have any recommendations for online tutorials to follow for this kind of work?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've been painting for 30 years. That sort of request is off-topic here anyway. YouTube is likely to have good help ready and waiting.